# How to replace path in file in docker container with perl or sed

Tags: bash, docker, perl, sed, replace

I am working on automation script that can set some parameters in docker container. I want to replace path `path.repo: /var/backups` with `path.repo: /var/log/elasticsearch` in yaml file in container so I use commands below:

```
old_path=/var/backups
new_path=/var/log/elasticsearch

docker exec elk sed -i '0,/${old_path}/s//${new_path}/' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

or

```
docker exec elk sed -i -E 's/^([^ ]*\s+)(\/var\/backups)(\s.*)/\1\2\/var\/log\/elasticsearch\3/' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

None of them is working. When I log in docker container and opening the yml file, it still remains same. Am I doing something wrong maybe with docker commands?
I also tried:

```
perl -i -p -e's{"/var/backups"}{/var/log/elasticsearch' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem with your first attempt is that setting variables in your local shell doesn't expose them inside your docker container (and using single quotes around your arguments prevents your *local* shell from expanding them)...and even if you were to substitute the variable values in that expression, the `/` characters in your path would muck with your `sed` command. The simplest solution here is probably something like this:

```
docker exec elk sed -i 's|/var/backups|/var/log/elasticsearch|' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

Note the use of `|` instead of `/` as the sed expression delimiter to avoid conflicts with the path separators. That only works with the `s` command, so if you really need to limit the scope of those changes with a search expression you'll need something like:

```
docker exec elk sed -i '0,/\/var\/backups/ s|/var/backups|/var/log/elasticsearch|' /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
```

That's pretty much the equivalent of your first example.

Having said that, editing content inside a running container is generally considered an anti-pattern: your best course of action is almost always to generate a new image with the changes baked in by using an appropriate `Dockerfile`.